# CSS fill remaining horizontal space and show an ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table-like-display containing 2 columns using div elements. One column is for an image URL while the other is for the file size. The file size column has a fixed width of 150px and the URL column should fill the remaining space. If there is insufficient space for the URL it should cut off and display an ellipsis. However what happens is the text just continues to the next line. I've also tried setting white-space: nowrap; but that causes the whole div to break onto a new line.

My HTML code look like this.

```
<div id="container>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="imageURL">http://mywebsite.com/image1.jpg</div>
        <div class="fileSize">586 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="imageURL">http://mywebsite.com/image2.jpg</div>
        <div class="fileSize">785 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="imageURL">http://mywebsite.com/image3.jpg</div>
        <div class="fileSize">258 KB</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    padding: 5px;
}
.imageURL {
    display: inline;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.fileSize {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something more like this in the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q33J/2/). I have rearranged your CSS to look like the following:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
}
.imageURL {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:65%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.fileSize {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;

}
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Mainly, I have added the white-space nowrap property along with keeping both divs on the same line, I took out the float, which had made it a block level element, and just placed a margin to be a specific amount from it. The key comes from the width in the .imageURL class, where I added an auto width, a min width, and a max width, which allows the ellipsis to take place at certain points.

Answer (score 0):

Change .imageURL to the following:

```
.imageURL {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Hope This Helps!;)

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/2qB2r/1/)